# alternative solution of full page cache for CE version

Tags: full-page-cache

I had used magento enterprise which include full page cache can be configured as served by redis, but how about in CE version of magento?

Is there any alternative solution available which performance is as good as FPC in enterprise?

Answer (score 0):

You can use lesti FPC or any Fpc extension.

Even you can setup rediss cache on server and setup in `local.xml`

Comment: in ce version, only session, backend can be cached by redis?

Comment: Yes you are right...